# Rust library for rank and select support on succinct int vectors, e.g. wavelet trees

Tags: library, file-compression, data-structure, rust

Is there a Rust library for Wavelet Trees or any other data structure that supports fast and memory-efficient rank and select on succinct integer vectors? [succinct](https://crates.io/crates/succinct), [succint_rs](https://crates.io/crates/succinct_rs) and [rsdict](https://crates.io/crates/rsdict) only seem to offer it for bit vectors but I need to store arbitrary integer values.

For example for C++ this is offered by the [SDSL](http://simongog.github.io/sdsl/a00305.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't find anything for a Wavelet Tree, the more modern data structure of the Wavelet Matrix seems to be better in most cases.
There are the crates [wavelet-matrix](https://crates.io/crates/wavelet-matrix) and [sucds](https://crates.io/crates/sucds/0.5.0).